# How to achieve frames per second in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl, requestanimationframe

Suppose I am drawing something to the canvas using WebGL in a `window.requestAnimFrame(somemethod);`

How to get the frames per second count?

For example, open this [Link](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/demos/webkit/SpiritBox.html) which shows the frames per second on top left corner.

How to achieve something similar using plain JavaScript? No API's please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` is not accurate, it may be delayed and/or stacked if one's doing heavy work, simply use the timestamp passed to the request animation frame callback.

```
var prev = 0;
requestAnimationFrame(function (now) {
    var delta = now - prev;
    var fps = 1000 / delta;
    prev = now;
    // render logic
});
```

Comment: What is now? is it some predefined number .

Comment: I would probably accept this one - more elegant and now is a timestamp https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 2):

in somemethod have global variable `counter` increased then add interval to log value

```
setInterval(function(){ console.log('fps:'+counter); counter=0; },1000);
```

Comment: How does a timer correlate with the number of frames per second drawn by WebGL?

Comment: each draw call is done by window.requestAnimFramer somemethod(), triggered so if you have a variable you increase on each draw call after a second you just see how many time you have called somemethod

Comment: Yup, that should work. I didn't understand what you mean in your answer at first, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: LJ's answer and this answer ,both looks promising, but which one I should accept as the correct answer ?

Comment: @subhfyu546754 accepting no answer is probably the worst thing you can do ;)